# What is the order of a function in distribution theory?

Tags: distribution-theory, ordered-fields

Let $\mathscr{D}(\mathcal{O})$ be the space of basic functions, $\phi$, which is equipped
with convergence, and where $\phi$ vanish outside of the set $\mathcal{O}$.

Let $\mathscr{D}'(\mathcal{O})$ be the space of generalized functions, which is also equipped with convergence, and where $(f_k,\phi_k)\longrightarrow 0 $, as $k\to\infty$.

Theorem ([Vladimirov](https://archive.org/details/vladimirov-genaralized-equations-in-mathematical-physics) page 13):
For a linear functional $f$ on $\mathscr{D}(\mathcal{O})$, to belong to the space of generalized functions $\mathscr{D}'(\mathcal{O})$, it is necessary and sufficient that for any open set $\mathcal{O}'\subset \mathcal{O}$ (where $\mathcal{O}'$ is also dense in $\mathcal{O}$), that there exists a number $K=K(\mathcal{O'})$ and $m=m(\mathcal{O}')$ such that

$$|(f,\phi)|\leq K ||\phi||_{C^m(\bar{\mathcal{O}'})'}$$

where  $\phi$ are the basic functions, $\phi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathcal{O'})$, $|(f,\phi)|$ is the value of the integral.

At first, I would have thought that $C^m$ is the space of continuous functions with $m$-norm. However, this is not true. In the [book](https://archive.org/details/vladimirov-genaralized-equations-in-mathematical-physics) by Vladimirov, $m$ is said to be the **order** of the function $f$ on the set $\mathcal{O}$.

Vldimirov further elaborates saying:

"The order of the delta function is for example 0, while the order of the generalized function $(f,\phi)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \mathcal{O}^{(k)}(k)$ is infinite. "

As an additional note, the order of the singular generalized function $\mathscr{P}\frac1x$  which forms the principal value of the integral of the function $\frac1x$ is on the other hand 1.

What is the best definition of order of a function in the given context of the generalized functions in distribution theory? I cannot find any other definition of the order here than in this theorem, and it seems more to be a integer that defines some property of the set $\mathcal{O}$ on which the basic functions are defined in.

Thanks

Comment: The distributional order of an $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ function is 0.

Comment: The distributional order of a locally summable  function is zero. Why?

Comment: I think that you're right that $C^m$ is the space of $m$ times differentiable functions. The *order* of the distribution is the smallest $m$ that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f\in L^\infty_{\text{loc}}$ the corresponding distribution is defined as
$$
\varphi \mapsto \int f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx.
$$

If $\operatorname{supp}\varphi \subseteq K$ we have
$$
\left| \int f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right|
= \left| \int_K f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right|
\leq \int_K |f(x)| \, |\varphi(x)| \, dx
\leq \int_K |f(x)| \, \sup_{x\in K}|\varphi(x)| \, dx
\\
= \int_K |f(x)| \, dx \cdot \sup_{x\in K}|\varphi(x)|
= C_K \|\varphi\|_{0},
$$
where $C_K = \int_K |f(x)| \, dx.$

Since we don't need to include any derivatives of $\varphi$ in the bound $C_k \|\varphi\|_{0}$, the distribution has order zero.

Comment: Here, K is the order?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. No, it's a compact set inside which $\varphi$ has its support.

Comment: So K is actually a measure, in order to make sense out of your integral inequality, or at least $C_K$

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. No, $K$ is not a measure; it's a compact set. I've edited the calculation to make it clearer that the integral, although it's first over all of space, is actually only over $K$ since $\varphi$ only lives inside $K.$

Comment: Thanks Per. On p .13 , it says that a set of locally summable functions $$(f,\phi)=\sum_{k>1}\phi^{(k)}(k)$$ has an infinite order. By a theorem in Vladimirov (p. 21-22), in order to form a measure, a generalized function has to have an order of zero.  So if the set of locally summable functions (which are a sufficient number of basic functions) has an infinite order, then it can't form a measure.

 We can then form a theorem saying that "A set of basic functions $\sum_{k>1}\phi^{(k)}(k)$, cannot alone form a measure on $\mathcal{O}$, since its order is infinite. "

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. Note that $(f,\phi)=\sum_{k>1}\phi^{(k)}(k)$ is one specific distribution, not some general construction. It's a standard example of a distribution of infinite order. It can also be written as $f=\sum_{k>1}(-1)^k\tau_k\delta^{(k)},$ where $\tau_a$ is the translation operator.

Comment: Hi Per. A specific distribution like the cap function for instance, or like the Gaussian bell function. They have infinite order, because they can actually  be composed of infinitely many summable functions, or because the can be infinitely differentiable? I try to relate the order to some known notion, such as diferentiability or number of summed functions.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. The order is basically the highest order of derivative of $\phi$ used. In $(f,\phi)=\sum_{k>1}\phi^{(k)}(k)$ derivates of all orders are used ($k=2,3,4,\ldots$) so the order is infinite. Distributions given by $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions, e.g. the Gaussian bell function, only depend on the value of $\phi,$ not on any derivatives, and so has order zero. The order doesn't have to be infinite just because the distribution can be decomposed into a series or is given a by an infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: Thanks, I think your last comment here answers everything. When I see that famous inequality from Vladimirov $$|(f,\phi)|\leq K||\phi||_{C^m(\bar{\mathcal{O}'})'}$$  it makes more sense, with $m$ being the order. The only thing that is missing in Vladimirov is an example, what example of a generalized function except the delta function, is there? I thought of the Fourier Transform $\int f(x)e^{−i\omega x}d\omega$ where $e^{−i\omega x}$ is the basic function. This basic function is infinitely differentiable. Does that mean the order of the example by Fourier transform is infinite too?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. The easiest example of a distribution of order $k$ is $\delta^{(k)}.$ I'm not sure what you mean with your Fourier example; how do you define $(f, \phi)$?

Comment: Per, right, the Fourier transform has nothing to do with generalized functions. One can take a Fourier transform of a generalized function, but the generalized functions are normally very few examples, such as the Dirac function and $\mathscr{P}\frac1x$, where the former is used for modeling a charge distribution or density distribution, and the latter the repulsion energy between two atoms. The elaboration of the concept by Vladimirov is so vaste and deep at the same time, that one would expect there are many examples of such generalized functions.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. Perhaps you should start with some more modern and not so heavy paper or book on distributions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the course book. What did you read?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz. Unfortunately I don't remember. We got some photocopied book. But my lecturer in functional analysis has written [these lecture notes](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf).

Comment: Hi Per, thanks for the link! I have downloaded the text and will follow it too. Merry Christmas.